# Difference in meaning

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference in meaning of the following sentences?

1. It will take two years to build a bridge on this river.
2. It would take two years to build a bridge on this river.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, though only a subtle one regarding likelihood.

Will, as a future tense, carries with it a bit of certainty. In your first sentence, the bridge is *expected* to be built and will take two years.

Would, as the past tense of will or as a conditional, indicates a possible or imagined situation. In your second sentence, the bridge *could* be built, and *if* it is, it will take two years.

Comment: In addition, would can add the condition that something necessary is missing for it to succeed.  "If we had the steel, it would take 2 years to build a bridge."

Answer (score 1):

`will` implies it has yet to happen and definitive

and `would` implies it has yet to happen but not definitive